# python pandas: convert/transform between iat/iloc and at/loc indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have the iloc index in a Dataframe and want the get the corresponding loc index. In other words: I would like to have a function `ilocIndex_to_locIndex` converting the `ilocIndex` to `locIndex`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1 : [1,2,3,4], 2 : [5,6,7,8]})
df = df.drop([1])
iatIndex = 2

df.iloc[ilocIndex]
locIndex = df.ilocIndex_to_locIndex(ilocIndex)
df.loc[locIndex]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subscript the `.index`:

```
>>> df.index[2]
3
```